# Error while converting from Vector to Euler angles (red link)

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using 3.1.

I'm linking the output of `Align Euler to Vector` (fed by a curve normal vector) to the `Rotation` input of `Transform`. So far, so good.

[image]

Spying on the value shows the rotation data is embedded in a `Vector`. XYZ components are π/2, π/4 and π/4 which is likely the correct rotation for my test case.

Now I'm adding a `Switch` with option `Vector` in order to be able to switch the rotation on/off:

[image]

The data type and value at `Output` of `Switch` have not changed, but the red link indicates a problem with the output. According to Blender [development documentation](https://developer.blender.org/rB65244ac1c3f1):

> This turns links red if no implicit conversion can be made between the
> from socket and the to socket. For geometry nodes this happens with
> object, geometry, collection, and string sockets that are connected to
> a different type.

---

- Why is there a conversion error? What is the underlying data type for `Rotation` input? I assume it is a `Vector` containing the 3 angles.
- How can I make this `Switch` node work?

---

Adding the test file:

[image]

Comment: The _Switch_ output has a diamond shape, and the _Transform_ inputs are circles. The connecting line is dashed, which means it carries a field of values, which means multiple values - and that doesn't mean three, because it's a vector, it means multiple vectors. The circle inputs tell you that they only accept single values - in this case, one vector, not multiple vectors. The _Geometry_ > _Transform_ node is used to transform the input geometry as a whole, not it's mesh or points individually. But the _Switch_ output assigns vectors to each point or vertex of the geometry individually.

Comment: It looks like you are using a single value for *Vector* as input in your first image, and yet in your second image you are feeding that input with the vectors of a geometry (which means, as @GordonBrinkmann has already correctly noted, that you are using one vector per element here). Please show us more of your node tree.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann: I understand what you said. However it seems the Switch node is inconsistent. For example without its inputs connected, it can only output one of the two constant preset vectors and the output mode (constant/series) should adapt. Anyway how to switch constants?

Comment: @mins ...it looks like your *Group Input* is a field (multiple elements, multiple values). But in this case you need a single value (single *Vector*). Please have a closer look at this part of the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html

Comment: @quellenform: The value of Point Location is provided by the property panel of the GN modifier (as this graph is the top level one), the interface allows both to provide a constant or to link to a driver (I think it's the name). In my case it is a constant, I could as well disconnect the Factor input and set it manually, [this would give this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUwjj.png) and Gordon explanation wouldn't apply.

Comment: @mins Important is the shape of the sockets when unconnected. An unconnected diamond might be able to take fields or single values. When the complete chain of connections works with a single value, the shape can switch from diamond to circle to indicate it's only processing a single value. Unconnected circle shapes however indicate they only work with single values on all accounts.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually fun that I can't reproduce it in 3.2 and even in 3.1, But there is an *Attribute Statistics* node, that can be used to convert field values to singular ones:

[image]

The actual problem in this node is that it has hidden connections. If we switch it back to geometry mode, they are show up:

[image]

Then I trim connections:

[image]

And back to vector mode, everything works fine:

[image]

This line indicates not an error in data, but actually a loop in parents:

[image]

Bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T100374

Comment: Ah ah, good trick. Would you mind adding the reason the link is red and the need for a conversion, to have a complete answer I could select?

Comment: I don't know, because I can't reproduce this issue. Drop file here: https://blend-exchange.com/ Maybe I miss something

Comment: Oh that's fun, It's a bug

Comment: I appreciate you took the time to dig down to the loop. So the red link is actually an indication of an invalid link, but not limited to casting problems...

Answer (score 2):

Switch the node `Switch` back to *Geometry* (Default setting). Then remove the existing connections. Then switch the node back to *Vector*.

The node remembers the connections you have tried before and will not be reset.

Comment: Good find. And a bug indeed.

Comment: @mins I wouldn't necessarily call it a "bug," but you're right: it does lead to a little confusion sometimes. ;-)

Comment: Switching geometries using inactive and hidden links while it should switch vectors using visible links... I call that a bug, not a feature.

Comment: If you find bugs, please post it here: https://developer.blender.org/
Thank you.

Comment: Already reported: https://developer.blender.org/T100374